# InterSystems ODBC drivers not connecting

Tags: odbc, windows-server-2019

Errors when trying to create a ODBC DSN.

Have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit InterSystems ODBC drivers (version 2018.1.2.309.0).

OS: Windows Server 2019 Version 1809

The 32-bit ODBC connection was working earlier. Maybe Windows Updates broke this connection, however I cannot find a relevant recently installed update.

A 32-bit ODBC connection is working from a different Server 2012 R2 server, the only difference being that it uses driver version 2014.1.3.775.0.

I also uninstalled the 32-bit driver and tried driver version 2014.1.5.851.3. Same connection error as below.

[image: ODBC Data Source Connevtivity Test Failed]

64-bit Driver:

```
Error Message: Connectivity test failed with doing the Test Connection:
Driver = C:\Windows\system32\CacheODBC64.dll
Driver Version = 2018.1.2.309.0

Data Source Name = CMS-ODBC
Host (IP Address) = 10.1.1.1
Port = 1404
Caché Namespace = NAME
Authentication Method = 0  - Password
User Name = odbc
Description = Reporting Database
Cache ODBC Logging = No
Use Locale Decimal symbol = No
Disable Query Timeout = 0
Static Cursors Support = 0
Unicode SQLTypes = 0

Connect Error: See CacheODBC.log for details

[Cache ODBC][State : S1000][Native Code 10054]
[C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe]
read_all:  recv() returned SOCKET_ERROR.  
Reason: (10054, 0x2746) An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

32-bit Driver:

```
Error Message:  Connectivity test failed: Invalid Host/Port; 
Caché Not Running; Network Down

Driver = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\InterSystems\Cache\CacheODBC.dll
Driver Version = 2018.1.2.309.0

Data Source Name = CMS-ODBC
Host (IP Address) = 10.1.1.1
Port = 1404
Caché Namespace = NAME
Authentication Method = 0  - Password
User Name = odbc
Description = Reporting Database
Cache ODBC Logging = No
Use Locale Decimal symbol = No
Disable Query Timeout = 0
Static Cursors Support = 0
Unicode SQLTypes = 0

Connect Error: See CacheODBC.log for details

[Cache ODBC][State : S1T00][Native Code 450]
[C:\Windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe]
Request timed out due to user timeout
```

Comment: Is the database server listening on port 1404? Can you verify that no firewall blocks it?

Comment: Yes the database server is listening on port 1404. I should updated the original post advising that the ODBC connection was working before.